# Method [delete] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working in a `laravel` application and trying to implement `delete()` method in a `controller` but it doesn't work. 
This is the `Error`:

```
BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 283: Method [delete] does not exist.
```

Here is my `view` (buss.blade.php)

```
 <a href="{!! URL::to('delete_bus', array($u->id)) !!}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
 </a>
```

Here is my Route:

```
Route::get('delete_bus/{id}', array('uses' => 'adminController@delete'));
```

and it exists in `app/resources/admin/buss.blade.php`

And Here is my `Controller Method`

```
public function delete_bus($id) {
        $reg = Business::find($id);
        $reg->delete();
        return Redirect::to('buss')->with('del', 'Sucessfully Deleted!');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your controller method `delete_bus`, but your trying to route to `delete` method. Change your route to this:

```
Route::get('delete_bus/{id}', array('uses' => 'adminController@delete_bus'));
```

And your controller should be called with capital letters, so this could be potential bug as well.

Comment: Such a trivial mistake! Thanks for Help!